# YouTube closed captions with API Player

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I'm noticing strange behavior with the YouTube iframe API and I'm looking for guidance. I'm trying to use the API to embed a video (or a playlist) which includes closed captioning enabled by default. The [YouTube docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#cc_load_policy) say to set `cc_load_policy=1` in the URL to show captions even if the user's preferences do not include them by default.

The problem is that **I get inconsistent behavior - seemingly at random - across YouTube.** Some videos show captions, others don't.

[Here's a working example](https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&cc_load_policy=1)

It's embed code is:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&cc_load_policy=1`

---

[Here's a non-working example](https://www.youtube.com/embed/y9sriE5VMQc?enablejsapi=1&cc_load_policy=1) using *the exact same embed code syntax*

Code:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/y9sriE5VMQc?enablejsapi=1&cc_load_policy=1`

**[Related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262666/youtube-closed-caption-for-html5-not-working)**

Does anyone have insight or thoughts into this behavior? Or is it a case of, "YouTube is a big website, wait a little longer?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering in case others are seeing the same behavior.

The `cc_load_policy` option with the iframe API only displays captions on videos that have caption files uploaded with them. The auto-captioning done by YouTube doesn't behave the same way. Apparently, this was done intentionally because the auto-captions aren't nearly as precise as a dedicated caption file. But, the docs make no mention of this.

Comment: This solution has stopped working from 13th June, 2017.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/XA6PIwXQCAc