# How can you enable automatic captioning in an embedded YouTube Video?

Tags: html, youtube

I am having a difficult time embedding a YouTube video with the auto captioning (CC) button toggle. I have searched and the only thing I could find was documentation from Google stating I could add cc_load_policy=1 to the URL string to enable this.

After researching on here I came across this post: [Youtube Closed Caption for HTML5 Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262666/youtube-closed-caption-for-html5-not-working). One of the commenters mentioned they also set cc_load_policy to 1, however it looks like this may not longer be supported in newer videos? Is there a definitive source that states whether or not we can use automatic captioning in embedded videos? I would have assumed this should be an easy feature to add.

Comment: Is this for videos you own or any video (including that you don't own the channel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive research and asking a good friend of mine who is a YT expert, no, it is not currently possible.

Only good workaround I see right now is Plyr: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr
Demo: https://plyr.io/

I tested it just now and it works great, but it's another plugin...

Exception: your own videos, you can turn CC on and it will reflect in the embedded versions, with a toggle button for CC (but will be on by default when the user plays the video on the page where it is embedded).

Cheers -